# How do I pass results from one Custom Query to another?

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau to create custom queries, I need to pass the results from one custom query into another. So for example one custom query might have the following query:

```
select * 
  from bime.test_tab 
 where record_date = '2018-05-21'.
```

I then create another custom query which uses the results from the query above. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can by making this custom query as a subquery

```
    select * from (select * 
    from bime.test_tab 
    where record_date = '2018-05-21') a
```

Answer (score 0):

As you might already know that we do not have a leverage to use temp tables in Tableau custom queries, hence we usually create subqueries for that.

Considering your case,

```
SELECT BIM_TABLE.* FROM 
(SELECT * FROM
 BIME.TEST_TAB WHERE RECORD_DATE= '2018-05-21')BIM_TABLE
```

You can post your actual problem with the relevant columns if you need further help.

PS - It's advised to do most of your data manipulations in SQL itself (if you are running your workbook on live connection), as Tableau is not able to properly optimize part of the 'Custom SQL' query.